# Json responce is not working properly

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a json object to my jsp. But for some reason it is behaving really weird sometimes its working and sometimes not working at all.

When i am trying to access it its giving me following dialogue box.

[image]

if i save the file and open it, it looks like

```
{"demandId":"WO.31.3.0","docSeries":31,"docNum":3,"docType":202,"docDate":"2015-05-05","docDueDate":"2015-06-05","itemCode":"RMSSMETALS001","docEntry":3,"priority":3,"id":4288,"quantity":10.0,"lineNum":0}
```

This much is fine i guess. but how should i send the response to my jsp.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/hello1", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Demand hello1(){
        //return(new ModelAndView("index", "command", new Student()));
        List<Demand> Demand= studentDaoImp.getdeDemands();
        return Demand.get(1);
    }
```

dispatcher servlet

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
          <property name="order" value="1" />
          <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
               <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
               <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
               <entry key="rss" value="application/rss+xml" />
            </map>
          </property>

          <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
              <!-- JSON View -->
              <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
              </bean>

             </list>
          </property>
          <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

        </bean>
```

anyone knows whats happening here. I would really appriciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should make an ajax request in "onload" event from jsp. You can use the same GET url.